# nodejs how to find the process id

Tags: node.js, linux, server, process

I have a nodejs application running on a live server. I start a new node process using the following command in Terminal of VSCODE by accessing the server through SSH.

```
nohup node filename.js &
```

Mostly I can see the process id using the following command in the VSCODE terminal.

```
netstat -lpn | grep 30001
```

This command gives the following output:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::30001                :::*                    LISTEN      21552/node
```

But, sometimes it doesnt show up any process id, as shown in the following output:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::30001                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

In case the process dies to due some technical error, it should get restarted automatically. I have executed the following code through a cron in every 5 minutes for this, which works.

```
const find = require('find-process');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

find("port", "30001")
    .then((list)=> {
        console.log("list::", list);
        if (!list.length) {
            spawn('node', [`${__dirname}/filename.js`], {
                detached: true,
                stdio: 'ignore'
            }).unref();
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err.stack || err);
    });
```

Following is my cron

```
*/5 * * * * node path-to-js-file/crontab.js
```

**My Question:**

1. Why my node instance on port 30001 is sometimes not having a pid while the application contained inside it is still accessible?
2. `kill -9` will need a Process Id which I dont have as showed above. How to kill such process through command so that it can be restarted?

Answer (score 3):

To show the proccess `pid` you can use the `process` module of nodejs.

```
var process = require('process');
console.log(`Process pid ${process.pid}`);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response but my query is about knowing the process id in SHELL, not in node. node is already handling it through cron. But if I need to restart the instance through kill -9 in SHEL, I dont have the pid. Also, why pid is not available through SHELL COmmand?

Comment: @ITSagar You could see the pid in a shell using the commend `ps`